# How can I test if a method was called with toHaveBeenCalled ? angular

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test, angular-testing-library

I have a function that update a variable, but in the coverage  its show me that function as if I had not tried it.
How can I test if a function was called ?
This is my function

```
 changePage(event) {
    this.currentPages = event.currentPage - 1;
  }
```

And this is my test

```
it('Should call the function',()=>{
    const newPage = {
      currentPage:1
    }
    component.changePage(newPage);
    expect(component.currentPages).toEqual(0);
    expect(component.changePage).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
```

[image]

Comment: I think the previous method is not covered not the current one!

Comment: Hi, excuse me, I don't understand, could you explain me please?

Comment: the screnshot is showing red, before the method declaration, so the previous line of code is only not covered please provide a bigger screenshot of the coverage

Comment: the previous line is not covered, but the function yes ?

Comment: yes that is what I think

Answer (score 0):

You can spy the function to test whether it has been called or not. Over here you want the original function to be executed + it should get called. Thus you should call `callThrough()` method on it.

```
it('Should call the function',()=>{
    const newPage = {
      currentPage:1
    }
    // Spy + Call original method implemention (callThrough)
    const spyChangePage = spyOn(component, 'changePage').and.callThrough();
    component.changePage(newPage);
    expect(component.currentPages).toEqual(0);
    expect(spyChangePage).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

Comment: hi, I tried it, the test passed, but the coverage is still red in that line :C

Comment: @SirRiT003 can you please update your question with full `spec` file code and code coverage picture?

Comment: I'ts necessary? I think that each test is independent right :?

Comment: es a file a little big

Comment: @SirRiT003 not necessary, can not think of any issue with the code that you have shown. I can not guess what it could be, if you're okay, you may share more relevant part of it.